# Use EF Core 6 "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold " generates context, but there is no ExecuteSqlCommand method

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I use

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
```

to get a `DbContext`; add, update, and delete are all OK.

But I want use raw SQL queries, like this:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs.FromSqlRaw("SELECT \* FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();
```

but my DbContext doesn't have this `FromSqlRaw` method

How to correct this error?

Comment: Have you added the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` package to your project? That's where this method is defined. EF Core connects to multiple database types, not just relational databases. Extension methods used in relational databases are added only when you add the relevant packages. If you add a specific database package, eg for SQL Server or PostgreSQL, the `Relational` package is added automatically as a dependency. If you don't, you'll have to add it explicitly.

Comment: Entity Framework Core provides the ```DbSet.FromSql()``` method to execute raw SQL queries for the underlying database and get the results as entity objects.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational has added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing a `using`.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: thank you，add using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore，that worked。